# Spring, Blob download, byte[] size increases twice

Tags: hibernate, spring, postgresql, arrays, blob

I am using Spring 3.0 with Hibernate and PostgreSQL and I have following problem:
I'm uploading the files to the database, saving its content type, and everything works ok, the size of the field in database is OK. However when I try to download it, Hibernate returns the byte array twice as bigger as it should. The downloaded files are corrupted of course. The size is ESXACTLY 2 times bigger then the size in database... My code looks as follow:
The field domain class (with mapping):

```
private byte[] cv;

@Column(name="cv")
public byte[] getCv() {
  return this.cv;
}
```

The DAO function that loads the object:

```
public Candidate load(Integer id) {
  return (Candidate) getHibernateTemplate().get(Candidate.class, id);
}
```

Session factory config:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan" value="foo.foo.core.domain"/>

</bean>
```

The SQL Create:

```
CREATE TABLE candidate
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  cv bytea,
  ...
)
```

The database is enncoded UTF-8 if it make any difference.
I was trying with org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler, but it does not do the thing.. Any ideas? It's driving me crazy..

Comment: Are you sure that wrong array is returned by Hibernate, and is not a result of some conversions afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the solution, change your DB setting for bytea output as follows:

ALTER DATABASE  SET bytea_output='escape';

Oscar.

Comment: If that fixes your problem, you can also solve it by updating your JDBC driver to version 9.0-801. That version supports Postgresql 9.0, which is when the bytea escape format changed to 'hex' (which is more efficient) by default.

Comment: Thats exactly what caused the problem. I've no idea why they did hexadecimal as default...

Comment: The variable-length bytea escape format was actually shown to be a performance bottleneck for fetching large values (as the server had to keep reallocating a buffer internally, iirc), which particularly affected tools like pg_dump. They figured that a major version upgrade was a reasonable time for introducing some non-backwards-compatible functionality.

Comment: This sounds like this will work for me! but I don't know how to run that command!

Comment: Okay, got it working with ALTER DATABASE "MyDbName" SET bytea_output='escape' -- thanks Oscar!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and still do not know how to solve it but it's for sure a codification problem.
I saved both images on disk and the wrong one is setting HEX codes for the char representation of the original codes, i.e

The original image starts with following bytes (HEX representation):

FF D8 FF E0 ...

The revovered byte array (double size) is as follows:

66 66 64 38 66 66 65 30 ...

Which happen to be the HEX codification of "ff d8 ff e0" as chars (f=66HEX)